# Как сделать чтобы гит добавлял файлы в коммит?

Tags: git, phpstorm

Дело в том, что при добавлении нового файла в проект, поставили галочку, которая делает так, что любой новый файл попадает в Unversioned Files. Как найти настройки, в которых можно сделать так, чтобы они все-таки добавлялись в гит? Редактор - PHPStorm

Comment: Settings > Version Control > Confirmation > When files are created - Add silently

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: @Spatz, напишите, пожалуйста, полноценный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В линейке продуктов на базе `IntelliJ IDEA`, в том числе и `PHPStorm`, для настроенных под `Git` проектов существует возможность автоматического добавления новых файлов в коммит.

Включить эту функцию можно в разделе настроек подтверждений для VCS.
Это: `File | Settings | Version Control | Confirmation` (или `Preferences | Version Control | Confirmation` для `macOS`).
В группе под названием `When files are created` нужно выбрать опцию `Add silently`.

[Здесь](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/settings-version-control-confirmation.html) можно узнать подробности про другие варианты настроек.